Doesn't start the tomcat server after running the spring boot application
My Spring Boot application doesn't start the Tomcat server after running it. localhost:8080 outputs
This site can't be reached.

Does intellJIDEA community edition required to install Tomcat separately or it comes with the Spring Boot project that initiated through Spring initializer?
application.properties file:
spring.application.name=hdfc-online-ticket
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/otrs
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=<undisclosed>
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#logging.level.root=TRACE

log file:
2024-05-13T09:36:52.476+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] c.t.h.HdfcOnlineTicketApplication        : Starting HdfcOnlineTicketApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 10964 (C:\Users\ishani.s\Downloads\HDFC\hdfc-online-ticket\hdfc-online-ticket\target\classes started by ishani.s in C:\Users\ishani.s\Downloads\HDFC\hdfc-online-ticket\hdfc-online-ticket)
2024-05-13T09:36:52.481+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] c.t.h.HdfcOnlineTicketApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-13T09:37:06.967+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-13T09:37:08.225+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1190 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2024-05-13T09:37:15.785+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-13T09:37:35.822+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@51c959a4
2024-05-13T09:37:35.838+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-13T09:37:38.034+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [           main] c.t.h.HdfcOnlineTicketApplication        : Started HdfcOnlineTicketApplication in 53.302 seconds (process running for 64.828)
2024-05-13T09:37:38.080+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-05-13T09:37:38.223+05:30  INFO 10964 --- [hdfc-online-ticket] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0

Main class:
@SpringBootApplication
public class HdfcOnlineTicketApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HdfcOnlineTicketApplication.class, args);
    }

}

pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ticket</groupId>
    <artifactId>hdfc-online-ticket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hdfc-online-ticket</name>
    <description>HDFC Onlie Ticketing System</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Do you have a dependency like spring-boot-starter-web? Please share pom.xml.

Mar-Z Yes. I have it.

You switched the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to provided. Depending on  your run confiugration in INtellij provided dependencies aren't included when running the application, make sure you enabled that checkbox if you didn't ther is no Tomcat to be detected.

From the title of the question I understand that you want Spring Boot to start the embedded Tomcat (default) and run your application on it. In this case you should remove the dependency:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency


It is not required, but if you use servlet initializer, then you can deploy your application to external Tomcat.
More detailed information you can get if you read How to use Spring Boot with existing Tomcat without war deployment answer.

If you want to use existing Tomcat instance you should deploy a war file to it. The instance is running it's own JVM and to hook into it you should provide ServletInitializer.

